# Windows data backups with alternating removable drives?

Tags: windows, backup, incremental-backup, windows-2000

I have a removable disk drive (RD1000 from Dell), and I am looking for backup software that will allow me to backup every night, and every morning switch to the alternate disk. There is only one directory structure to back up, what I want is two copies, one which I will take home with me every night, one which will be backing up every night, and when I get in in the morning, I will switch them.

So for instance I have disk "a" and disk "b". On Monday night I want to go home with disk "a" and leave disk "b" in the drive, so that a scheduled back up will be written to it. On Tuesday morning I will come in and swap disks, and I will take "b" home that night, leaving "a" for the backup. And so on for the remainder of the week.

FOSS software preferred, Freeware acceptable, paid software as a last-ditch effort.

Oh, btw I'm stuck with Windows 2000

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 2000?  You could just use NTBackup and have it write the bkf file to the hard drive.  I don't have any more machines with Win2000, so I can't give any details about that version of NTBackup, but it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: sounds like a viable option, do you know whether or not NTBackup keeps multiple versions of files?

Comment: What do you mean multiple versions?  NTBackup will basically just copy the one directory tree you want into a single file called whatever_you_want.bkf  I think the only way you could keep multiple versions is by changing the name of the .bkf file each time.  You'll have to play with it a bit.

Comment: Actually, based on your comment, you might just want to use rsync or one of the similar commercial (but cheap) tools like SecondCopy.

Comment: It's a long time since I've used ntbackup, but if memory serves you can set a job to append.  Your scenario would be creating two identical jobs but going to different destinations and running on alternate days, configured to append if possible.